# Grounding issues when using multiple supplies

Tags: grounding, dual-supply

I have a few questions about how grounding on a PCB and to an enclosure should be done when using multiple supplies.  I have read a number of similar questions/answers from multiple sources with the most definitive being

[Should chassis ground be attached to digital ground?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19561/should-chassis-ground-be-attached-to-digital-ground)

However this doesn't quite answer my questions for this specific case.

I have a single PCB board that has two circuits: one (denoted TC) powered by a +/- 5 V split supply, and the other (denoted CC) by a +/- 15 V supply. Both circuits are connected to a 14-pin butterfly package and everything is to be housed inside a metal enclosure. Only one pin of the butterfly package is connected to the case and only to the case. For heatsinking reasons, the case is mounted to the metal enclosure. A basic layout is as shown:

[image]

The two circuits are separated, so in principle could have separate grounds. Due to the pin configuration of the butterfly package, current (~0.5-1 A) return for TC is on the CC side of the board. A separate trace could easily be routed for the return, but the lowest impedance return would be along the edge of the board anyway.

The CC circuit includes a DAC (AD5790) that is programmed by an on-board Arduino Nano BLE.  The Arduino board is independently powered and the DAC has its own 3.3 V digital supply (derived from the +15 V).  The intention is that the Arduino is only used intermittently and can be powered down and disconnected when not in use. The DAC placement and routing is such that the digital part is separate from the analog parts of the board. The Arduino has its own board but can be hard soldered to a PCB. My intention would be to connect its GND to the GND plane of the PCB. I don’t think there is any other way to (easily) attach the GND e.g. through the USB connection.

Powering the TC from the same 15 V split supply is not really an option as it will result in unnecessary power dissipation (5-10 W).

My questions are:

1. The datasheet for the DAC suggests a separate GND for DGND and AGND and only connect it at one point to “avoid ground loops”. Given that I routed the DAC signals on the top layer immediately above the ground plane and away from the analog section, is there any reason to separate the GNDs?  One argument I read was that signals will propagate such that return currents will remain under the signal traces and such a separation is unnecessary and more likely to cause problems. If they should be separate, where would the single connection point be?
2. Should TC and CC have a separate GND planes?  Given they a physically separated anyway this seems a little redundant but they are connected to two different supplies.
3. How should the supplies be brought into the enclosure? I considered screw-in feedthrough capacitors for the supplies and turrets for the ground lines with the hope of killing any high frequency on the supply lines but wondered if these would be better isolated from the enclosure given the two separate supplies.
4. How should the enclosure be grounded?  From the link above it seemed that the “best” solution would be to use mounting holes for the PCB that are plated and connected to the GND plane(s) to tie the PCB to the enclosure, but I assume this depends on how everything else is (should be) done.

Regarding the supplies, any advice on the cables would be appreciated. The enclosure will sit probably 5 m away from the supplies and I am concerned about what might get picked up from everything else in the lab (often in the range of a few MHz to a few hundred MHz).

Comment: It's a well elaborate question, but too broad in scope for SE I'm afraid. A thorough answer would be almost an essay. Probably easier to focus it more, and make a follow up question later to address other dependent issues. Therefore voted to close for more focus and +1.

Comment: @tobalt - seriously?  I don't think it could be more definitive on exactly what the set up actually is.  If you don't know the answer or have nothing helpful to say, why dictate that others shouldn't be able to.  How entitled can you get?

Comment: Ye seriously. And you maybe calm down a little and consider advice when you get it. I would have things to say, but I don't want to write essays for free :) I'm not dictating anything either. It is a *vote* after all.. Again I think these are all good questions and I upvoted, but should be split IMO.

Comment: @tobalt.  The fundamental question here is grounding when using multiple supplies to a common PCB.  It is the paradigm example one encounters in any lab situation.  Multiple equipment that is interconnected and powered from multiple sources. The addition questions are more to provide clarification on potentially relevant information and I have explicitly put my thoughts on that.  If not there, people would be equally likely to say there is not enough information to make any comment.  Indeed the DAC is powered from multiple sources and connected to another device - so same thing