# Did I design this filter correctly?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, filter, sallen-key

I am about to place/route and order my PCB for this subcomponent. It essentially takes in a low-amplitude analog signal from a 1/4" jack, adds a 1.65V bias, amplifies, and filters off any high frequencies.

I know that this circuit could have potentially be designed more efficiently (as in using less op-amps), but I wanted to keep it simple.

Does anyone see any mistakes? Will this circuit work as intended?

[image: Analog]

Comment: I was about to suggest NE5532 until I realized you run at 3.3 V.

Comment: Please list the way the circuit is supposed to operate as intended.

Comment: What output amplitude are you expecting to work with?

Comment: Is there a [bypass capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237079/how-to-chose-the-right-decoupling-bypass-capacitor-variant-for-opamp-power-rails) at each opamp?

Comment: You can add bias to the gain stage and avoid that first op amp, in fact you already have it wired for that behavior. Also check out the filter design tool on Analog Devices' website, it's really an incredible resource for active filter design, especially for higher order/multi stage designs.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "no pop" resistors?  They look wrong!

Comment: Rydberg, I'd like to hear your thoughts about why the offsetting opamp is first, the gain stage is 2nd, and the filter is 3rd.

Comment: Values for R24, R25, C4, and C6 are not Butterworth or Chebyshev.  Are they just placeholders?

Comment: For the filter, I get \$Q\approx1.58\$ and \$\omega_{_0}\approx 5100\$ (or \$f_{_0}\approx 812\:\text{Hz}\$.) It should have a \$+4.44\:\text{dB}\$ peak  (rarely go beyond \$+3\:\text{dB}\$ for 2nd order unless it is part of a larger filter system) at \$f\approx 726\:\text{Hz}\$. Those are computed and rounded, not simulated. (Part value tolerances will be somewhat tougher to meet with such a Q, as well.) But the frequency I see is nothing like the \$2.5\:\text{kHz}\$ that appears in the schematic (unless being \$-19\:\text{dB}\$ is the desire there.)

Comment: Rydberg, the reason I ask about your series arrangement (no necessary argument, but I don't know the input signal case) is that if the input signal is noisy enough that fluctuations may overload an amplifier stage then it may be helpful to apply a filter to the input, first, in order to attenuate the perturbations outside the bandwidth of interest. More than likely you have things arranged right. But I just want to hear from you about it, first.

Comment: @Rydberg Did you intend to label C6 as 0.01uF instead of 0.1uF. If C6 was 0.01uF then fc (-6 dB) frequency would be about 2.5 kHz as you indicate?

Comment: What is the intention of the circuit to know if it works as intended? What is the signal source impedance to estimate if the input stage is OK? If input is AC coupled can the stages be DC coupled? What specific response you need from the Sallen Key filter, which cut-off, how much attenuation at what frequency and what you intend to do with the signal? Sample it with ADC? Which ADC and which sampling rate to know if the output can drive it?

Answer (score 4):

### Quick overview

In general, your approach is basically okay. In usual cases, it is (as you show) better to provide the gain (which applies to both noise and signal) first and then apply the filter. (The counter-case would be if the noise was sufficient to cause the opamp voltage gain stage to *rail* -- in that case filtering *first* might help some.)

Some practical points; one important and one not so much so:

1. You *will* likely need a small capacitor across stage 1 opamp between the output and the (-) input. A \$220\:\text{pF}\$ would be fine and won't impair your filtering, later.
2. You *may* want a galvanic connection from the input at the jack to ground. Something light, like \$330\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

### Serious problem

The elephant in the room is that your supposed \$f{_0}=2.5\:\text{kHz}\$ filter -- isn't. Instead, \$f_{_0}\approx 812\:\text{Hz}\$ with \$Q\approx 1.58\$. This means your frequency is ***way off*** and you are using a \$Q\$ that is unusually high for a solo 2nd order filtering stage.

I've no idea how you got there from a specification of \$f{_0}=2.5\:\text{kHz}\$.

### Analysis

The analysis of your circuit provides (using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)):

```
eq1 = Eq( v1/r24 + v1/r25 + v1/(1/s/c6), v2/r25 + vin/r24 + vout/(1/s/c6) )
eq2 = Eq( v2/r25 + v2/(1/s/c4), v1/r25 )
eq3 = Eq( vout/(1/s/c6), iout + v1/(1/s/c6) )
eq4 = Eq( vout, v2 )
tf = tf2( solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4 ], [ vout, v1, v2, iout ] )[vout]/vin )
tf
{omega: 1/(sqrt(c4)*sqrt(c6)*sqrt(r24)*sqrt(r25)),
 zeta: sqrt(c4)*(r24/2 + r25/2)/(sqrt(c6)*sqrt(r24)*sqrt(r25)),
 P: [{A: 1, N: 0}]}
```

(I define the **tf2** function [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/570978/38098).)

From the above I find that \$f_{_0}\$ is:

```
(tf[omega].subs( { r24:6.2e3, r25:6.2e3, c4:10e-9, c6:100e-9 } )/2/pi).n()
811.761485556243
```

And that \$Q\$ is:

```
1/(2*tf[zeta].subs( { r24:6.2e3, r25:6.2e3, c4:10e-9, c6:100e-9}) )
1.58113883008419
```

And that the peaking frequency, relative to \$f_{_0}\$, is:

```
sqrt( 1 - 1/2/1.58113883008419**2 )
0.894427190999916
```

So the peak gain will be at the peaking frequency of \$f= f_{_0} \cdot \sqrt{1-\frac1{2\,Q^2}}\approx 726\:\text{Hz}\$ with a peak of \$20\cdot\log_{10}\left(\frac{2\,\cdot\,Q^2}{\sqrt{4\,\cdot\,Q^2-1}}\right)\approx 4.437\:\text{dB}\$.

Which is unusual for a single 2nd order low-pass stage and puts a slight extra burden on the precision of the parts you select, too.

### Summary

In the particular low-pass filter you have designed, it is almost \$-19\:\text{dB}\$ at \$2.5\:\text{kHz}\$. I don't suppose that's what you really wanted.

So my final answer is that the circuit, while mostly right in terms of basic form, won't do what you appear to want.

### Note about filter passives

If you really want \$f_{_0}\approx 2.5\:\text{kHz}\$ and want to keep the input impedance near where you already have it for the filter, then perhaps consider \$R_{24}=R_{25}=7.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$C_4=3.3\:\text{nF}\$ and \$C_6=22\:\text{nF}\$. This sets \$Q\approx 1.291\$ and limits the peaking to about \$+2.9\:\text{dB}\$, which is close to a \$+3\:\text{dB}\$ Chebyshev that provides the fastest *initial* falloff, *acceptable* gain ripple, and continual attenuation in the stopband, on balance.

### Appendix: Derivation of \$\sqrt{1-\frac1{2\,Q^2}}\$ and \$\frac{2\,\cdot\,Q^2}{\sqrt{4\,\cdot\,Q^2-1}}\$

Those expressions are valid only for cases where \$Q\ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}2\$ (or \$\zeta\le \frac{\sqrt{2}}2\$), as other cases produce a peaking frequency ratio, \$\frac{f}{f_{_0}}\$, that is imaginary.

The first expression tells us that \$\rho=\frac{\omega_{_\text{PEAK}}}{\omega_{_0}}=\frac{f_{_\text{PEAK}}}{f_{_0}}=\sqrt{1-\frac1{2Q^2}}\$.

To find this result, just realize that the maximum value (peak value) will occur when the derivative of the magnitude (when \$s=j\omega\$) of the characteristic is zero (hopefully, a minimum and not a maximum.)

In standard form (one of them, anyway) the characteristic is \$\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1\$.

Substituting in \$s=j\omega\$ then gives \$1-\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+j\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)\$.

The characteristic magnitude is: \$\sqrt{\left[1-\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2\right]^2+\left[\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\right)\right]^2}\$ or \$\sqrt{\left[1-\rho^2\right]^2+\left[\frac{\rho}{Q}\right]^2}\$.

Take the derivative of this magnitude and set that it zero, then solve for \$\omega\$.

Let's add a change of variable so that \$\tilde{\rho}=\rho^2\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\rho}\left[\sqrt{\left(1-\rho^2\right)^2+\left(\frac{\rho}{Q}\right)^2}\right] &= 0
\\\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\rho}\left[\left(\rho^4-2\rho^2+1\right)+\frac{\rho^2}{Q^2}\right] &= 0
\\\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\rho}\left[\rho^4+\left(\frac{1}{Q^2}-2\right)\rho^2+1\right] &= 0
\\\\
2\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\tilde{\rho}}\left[\tilde{\rho}^2+\left(\frac{1}{Q^2}-2\right)\tilde{\rho}+1\right] &= 0
\\\\
2\tilde{\rho}+\left(\frac{1}{Q^2}-2\right) &= 0
\\\\
\tilde{\rho}_{_\text{PEAK}}=\tilde{\rho} &=1-\frac1{2Q^2}
\\\\
\therefore \rho_{_\text{PEAK}}=\rho &= \sqrt{1-\frac1{2Q^2}}
\end{align*}$$

(Note that a higher \$Q\$ indicates the peak will be higher (as we'll soon see) and closer to \$f_{_0}\$. In the limit where \$Q\to\infty\$ the peak will be exactly at \$f_{_0}\$. And in lowpass filters where \$Q\to\frac{\sqrt{2}}2\$ the peak will be ever lower and rapidly ever closer towards DC.)

The second expression mentioned in the subtitle can be found by substituting the above result back into the magnitude:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{dB}_{\rho_{_\text{PEAK}}}&=20\log_{10}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\left[1-\rho_{_\text{PEAK}}^{\,2}\right]^2+\left[\frac1{Q}\rho_{_\text{PEAK}}\right]^2}}\right)
\\\\
&=20\log_{10}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\left[1-\tilde{\rho}_{_\text{PEAK}}\right]^2+\frac{\tilde{\rho}_{_\text{PEAK}}}{Q^2}}}\right)
\\\\
&=20\log_{10}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\left[1-\left(1-\frac1{2Q^2}\right)\right]^2+\frac{1-\frac1{2Q^2}}{Q^2}}}\right)
\\\\
&=20\log_{10}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\frac{Q^2-\frac14}{Q^4}}}\right)=
20\log_{10}\left(\frac{Q^2}{\sqrt{Q^2-\frac14}}\right)
\\\\
&=20\log_{10}\left(\frac{2Q^2}{\sqrt{4Q^2-1}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

The above could have been used to solve, instead, for the magnitude at any \$f\$. Not just \$f_{_\text{PEAK}}\$. If you set \$\tilde{\rho}_{_f}=\left[\frac{f}{f_{_0}}\right]^2\$ for \$f\ge 0\$ then:

$$\text{dB}_{{\tilde{\rho}_{_f}}}=-10\log_{10}\left(\left[{\tilde{\rho}_{_f}}-1\right]^2+\frac{\tilde{\rho}_{_f}}{Q^2}\right)$$

When \$\tilde{\rho}_{_f}=1\$ then \$\text{dB}_{1}=20\log_{10}\left(Q\right)\$. Convenient!

Answer (score 1):

I simulated your peaked low frequency and my Butterworth near your needed 2500Hz:
[image: SK filter]