# Books on Bypassing, decoupling and Grounding

Tags: grounding, decoupling-capacitor, bypass, bypass-capacitor

I am really sorry to ask this question but I am new to PCB designing and Its pretty challenging for me. The layout works in LAB but does not work well outside. I observe glitches in system. I am a beginner and i want to follow the best practices and industry standards. So I would be grateful if someone can suggest be a good book on these topics. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/High-Speed-Digital-Design-Handbook/dp/0133957241

Comment: Asking for book recommendations is probably off-topic (see [Help](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) but also see [this related question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/15135/52562) for some guidance.

Comment: Books by Howard Johnson, Eric Bogatin, Henry Ott and Ralph Morrison are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal and Power Integrity - Simplified (2nd Edition) Eric Bogatin is a great resource if you're just starting out and the front few sections do a fantastic job of describing inductance and capacitance in detail.   Also these guys like Bogatin and Johnson have great websites full of useful info:

http://www.bethesignal.com/bogatin/
https://www.sigcon.com/

I'd also recommend the video series by Johnson.

Answer (score 2):

"Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering" by Henry Ott, chapter 11.

Many chip makers have app-notes & other design resources dealing with decoupling caps, for example this from TI related specifically to BGA packages (decoupling techniques can get fairly specific to the ic package type - what works for thru-hole DIP is very different to what works for high density SMT):
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/General_hardware_design/BGA_PCB_design/BGA_decoupling

http://www.interfacebus.com/Design_Capacitors.html (& related pages)

The other 2 links commented under your OP are also very useful.