# GND'ing of SMD components on top layer

Tags: pcb

I am working on a 2 layer Teensy 2.0 clone.

What is a recommended way of connecting GNDs on the top layer to the GND layer (bottom layer)? Should I use through-hole for every GND pads or can I do a GND pour on the top layer (and as well as on the bottom layer)?

Comment: [This](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/decoupling-caps-pcb-layout) question has answers that might interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a VIA or two connected to the GND layer next to each GND pad. Depending on the density of your design, a GND pour can be almost impossible on the routing layer. Avoid routing on the  bottom layer (GND Plane) by all means.

Comment: Out of interest, why avoid routing on the ground plane?

Comment: Interruptions in the ground plane prevent electrical continuity and disrupt current flow effectively. This leads to lengthening the return path. This increase in circuit loop area increases the path inductance. (see https://cloud.botnic.ch/index.php/s/RaXW23r3JohT7iJ for picture)