# Is it ok to replace a tantalium decoupling capacitor with ceramic?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, ceramic, tantalum

I am using the Analog Devices ADXL343 accelerometer (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL343.pdf) which advises using a 1uF tantalium cap on one power line, and a 0.1uF ceramic on the other.  I can't see any reason to prefer tantalium - ceramics of that size are easily available in my preferred 0402 chip size, and a fraction of the cost.  Am I missing something?  On Digikey tantalium cap one-off is about £1.50 but ceramic just 8 pence!

Comment: from the datasheet (which you could have linked for a better question and to attract good answers), they suggest either 1 or 10µF. while small form factor of ceramic 1µF exist, im not so sure about 10µF. Also, the technology is only a suggestion. You have to think about desirable qualities for decoupling capacitors, and how tantalum and ceramic measure up against those expectations

Comment: Thank you!  Link added.  I have to admit I don't really understand how difference between the two will affect how the decoupling works.  I have read a few things on the web but tends to talk about stability of capacitance with temperature/voltage which doesn't really affect me.  Question probably is exactly that - how does tantalium vs ceramic affect desirable qualities for decoupling capacitors?

Comment: "Below 10 kHz the ESR of ceramic capacitors increases, so tantalum or aluminium electrolytic capacitors are recommended in this frequency range" That possibly explains tantalum for Vs. https://www.dataweek.co.za/news.aspx?pklnewsid=27008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine.

The choice of decoupling capacitors is one of those matters that can either solved with "slap 0.1µF on that" or weeks of analysis.

what you want is a big reserve of charges to allow your chip to pull current without dropping the supply voltage, and a small but low ESR (equivalent serie resistance) cap to shunt the high frequencies that could come from it.

As a rule of thumb, 1µF + 0.1µF, both in ceramic, should be fine for the most common applications, including yours. I recommend reading up on the subject, it has helped me drastically as a designer. [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/decoupling-caps-pcb-layout/15143#15143) and [this application note](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-101.pdf) are good starting points.